# appcelerator tableview seprators not showing

Tags: tableview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

the separators in tableview are not showing
eg.

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var tableData = [ {title: 'Apples'}, {title: 'Bananas'}, {title: 'Carrots'}, {title: 'Potatoes'} ];

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
data: tableData
});
win.add(table);
win.open();
```

I have also tried

```
table.separatorStyle = Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewSeparatorStyle.SINGLE_LINE; 
table.separatorColor = "#000";
```

also tried running kitchsink,the separators are not showing at all

any ideas?

Comment: Can you please specify the platform name(iOS or Android) and Ti SDK version. because as I checked this code is working fine for iOS and  Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewSeparatorStyle.SINGLE_LINE;  is iOS only property.

Comment: yes I am trying on ios platform with SDK - 5.1.2.GA

Comment: update - the seprators were not showing on iphone 6 simulator but show when I install it on device but the top row separator and bottom row separator are still not displayed

Comment: Separator will display only between two rows of tableView. if you want then you can create tableview row and set borderColor as workaround

Comment: @sachinmw you probably didn't see them in the simulator because the display was downsized to fit your monitor and the lines are so thin they don't show. I've seen that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use ListViews instead of TableViews: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/ListViews

They give a huge performant boost on large lists. Also you have a better handling the design while using templates for ListItems.